# Why is large MySQL database crashing app?

Tags: openshift

I have a webapp which I'm trying to deploy to OpenShift, which serves historical plots of market data. The MySQL database is around 600MB and has >12,000,000 rows over about 6 tables. If I deploy and run the app, it may run at most a couple minutes, but then it crashes with exceptions related to null database connections. I tried restarting mysql and looking at the quota (~750MB of 1024MB) to no avail. If I reduce the database size drastically, the webapp runs fine. So far a couple hours with no crashes. I also have another webapp on OpenShift that uses a small MySQL database that runs just fine.

From what I could tell from reading the documentation is that a gear provides up to 1 GB of storage, and I'm under that amount. If I lower my data footprint drastically, MySQL behaves fine. Any ideas regarding why with a 600MB database, the app fails and what limitations are causing failure? The webapp has also been running solidly on a VPS for about 2 years with no issues, so I'm pretty confident the problem lies within OpenShift's MySQL cartridge.

Edit: Additional Information

- The MySQL cartridge is on a small gear and shared with the webapp.
- The number of connections is 5 from a pool

Comment: What size gear are you running the MySQL cartridge on?  Is it running on the same gear as your web cartridge? (are you running a scaled application so that the database is on its own gear?)  How many connections are you trying to make to the database at one time? etc...

Comment: To see what's using up space you can run `du -h * | sort -rh | head -50' inside the gear to get a list of the things that are using the most space. It would also be good to know what kind of application you're deploying. the default amount of space for a gear is 1GB but that's for everything. So if you're running a non-scalable app the database and your code and any other data all live in that one gear. If its a scalable app then your database and the application become separated.